# Objective C: Memory Leak due to 'Incorrect decrement of reference count'

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I am hitting the below memory leak warning after analyzing my code.

[image]

However, the warning is not showing up within my code to tell me exactly where this leak is happening. Can anyone advise me on what usually cause this leak and how can I search my code to identify it?

Comment: Can you show the code near where an object is released? It is likely that an object is getting over-released.

Comment: If you click on the line you will found the piece of code.

Comment: Does objective-c have any forceful `delete` or `release` operations that would decrement the reference count? If so, I would check for these. What you posted gives me the feeling of something being released, and then going out of scope or something, and therefore getting released again.

Comment: Looks like you `release` an object you got from another function/method. Use `autorelease` from the function/method to relinquish ownership of the object while still returning a valid reference.

Comment: @Rahul, I tried clicking but nothing showed up in the code

Comment: try nikita zhuk's clang static analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

According to Cocoa naming convention, methods other than ones starting with `init`, `new`, `copy` or `mutableCopy` must return self-owned or autoreleased object. The caller must also aware that the object returned from the methods need no releasing.